# TSQL Continuous Membership for specific Period of time, simplify WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need find members who can have multiple membership periods (with overlaps and gaps). Main condition is that they have to be active every single day withing @Start and @Date. I made core code but having problem filtering out some bad cases, in my sample data those marked with 'X'. My code works partially. Can't figour out they way plug in `@Start` day

While progressing on my code I gradually sank into too many series of `OR` and `AND`. Is there some better solution you think. I just realized that I need to test each `Code` if it's active for every single day in my period (180 days). I start thinking that maybe going into the loop is more simple solution.

My table has 100000 rows for 30,000 `Codes`.

```
/*
  create table dbo.Test ( code varchar(20), datefrom date, dateTo date)
 truncate table dbo.test   --       select * from dbo.test
 INSERT INTO dbo.Test        (Code, DateFrom , DateTo )
         SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','01/01/2012','7/22/2018' UNION ALL
         SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','7/30/2018','11/01/2018' UNION ALL
         SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','11/02/2018','12/31/2018'       UNION ALL
         SELECT '2_OK_grp','01/01/2018','11/11/2018' UNION ALL
         SELECT '2_OK_grp','11/12/2018','12/31/2018' UNION ALL
         SELECT '33_OK_single','01/02/2018','01/02/2019' UNION ALL
         SELECT '44_X_single','06/03/2018','12/12/2018' union    ----  single ends early   12/31
         SELECT '5_X_grp','01/01/2018','8/8/2018' UNION ALL       ----  ends early   12/31
     SELECT '5_X_grp','8/9/2018','12/22/2018'  union all  ----  ends early   12/31
     SELECT '6_Xe_grp','7/7/2018','10/10/2018' UNION ALL  ----  starts late  7/1
     SELECT '6_Xe_grp','10/11/2018','2/22/2019' UNION ALL
     SELECT '7_OK_grp','5/5/2018','10/10/2018' UNION ALL  ----  OK overlap  
     SELECT '7_OK_grp','7/7/2018','8/8/2018' union all
     SELECT '7_OK_grp','10/10/2018','3/3/2019'
  */


--- Given period to check for continuity
DECLARE @Start DATE = '2018-7-1', @End DATE = '2018-12-31';

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        LEAD(dateFrom) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY DateFrom) LeadFrom,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, dateto, LEAD(dateFrom) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY DateFrom)) - 1 DaysGap,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, dateto, @End) DaysTillEnd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY DateTo) RankS
    FROM 
        test    
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE   
    ((EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.code = cte.code AND c2.DaysGap <= 0)   -- Gap with for group
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.code = cte.code AND c2.RankS > 1)
     AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.code = cte.code AND c2.DaysTillEnd <= 0))   
    OR
    (LeadFrom IS NULL AND DaysTillEnd <= 0                                               -- single
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.code = cte.code AND c2.RankS > 1))
    )
    AND rankS = 1  -- pik just one code, don't care about dates
```

I expect only 3 code records with `OK` be displayed. Dates doesn't matter.

```
2_OK_grp    2018-01-01  2018-11-11
33_OK_single    2018-01-02  2019-01-02
7_OK_grp    2018-05-05  2018-10-10
```

Comment: Can you please post your expected result? Also, well done for providing DDL and DML for your sample data, however, please do avoid ambiguous date formats. There aren't 22 months in the years, for example, so your statement (as it is), will fail for a lot of people; meaning they need to amend it to make use of it. Thanks,

Comment: Use a calendar table, calculate amount of days between Start and End, and join the ranges of each code against the calendar table with Start and End boundaries. If amount of days match then the code has all days.

Comment: Tx all, looks like i'm moving into DimDates

Comment: I moved to DimDate, just need check overlaps now.

Comment: It's not clear why you expect the row with `2018-11-11` to be included when the end date is `2018-12-31`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the problem fully, but whenever i encounter date/periodicity problems I try to explore options using spt_values, or if [master] database is not available, a dedicated date dimension table. Given the problem and data volumes I would explore in this direction (but would like to hear other's opinion on the the applicability of window functions to this problem). I also like to apply joining to dimDate because most of the time in my case the date table is a optimized lightweight table that contains the required reference data for my operation.

I would then play around with semi-joins to DimDate (something along the lines of

```sql
select * 
from @tab t JOIN DimDate dd ON dd.[date] BETWEEN t.StartDt AND t.EndDt)
```

and potentially employing EXISTS / NOT EXISTS to fulfil my filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with DimDate looks very nice and easy to read:Tx all again.

```
/*
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '20180701', '20190101'))  
        DATEADD(dd,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1,'20180701') dt
 INTO dbo.Calendar
  FROM sys.all_columns sc1,         sys.all_columns sc2;           --             drop table Calendar

--  select * from Calendar  --184
*/
with cte as (
   SELECT t.*,  c.dt
   FROM   test  t
   join Calendar c on c.dt  between t.DateFrom  and t.DateTo     
)
 select Code, count(Distinct dt) from cte
 group by Code
 Having count(Distinct dt) <> 184
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple common table expressions

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE( code VARCHAR(20), datefrom DATE, dateTo DATE)

INSERT INTO @Test(Code, DateFrom , DateTo )
SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','01/01/2012','7/22/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','7/30/2018','11/01/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT '1_Xgap_Grp','11/02/2018','12/31/2018'       UNION ALL
SELECT '2_OK_grp','01/01/2018','11/11/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT '2_OK_grp','11/12/2018','12/31/2018' UNION ALL
SELECT '33_OK_single','01/02/2018','01/02/2019' UNION ALL
SELECT '44_X_single','06/03/2018','12/12/2018' union    ----  single ends early   12/31
SELECT '5_X_grp','01/01/2018','8/8/2018' UNION ALL       ----  ends early   12/31
SELECT '5_X_grp','8/9/2018','12/22/2018'  union all  ----  ends early   12/31
SELECT '6_Xe_grp','7/7/2018','10/10/2018' UNION ALL  ----  starts late  7/1
SELECT '6_Xe_grp','10/11/2018','2/22/2019' UNION ALL
SELECT '7_OK_grp','5/5/2018','10/10/2018' UNION ALL  ----  OK overlap  
SELECT '7_OK_grp','7/7/2018','8/8/2018' union all
SELECT '7_OK_grp','10/10/2018','3/3/2019'

DECLARE @Start DATE = '2018-7-1', @End DATE = '2018-12-31';
WITH codes AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT code FROM @Test
),
dates AS
(
    SELECT thedate = @Start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate)
    FROM dates
    WHERE dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate) <= @End
)
SELECT * 
FROM codes c
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM dates d1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM @Test t2
        JOIN dates ON thedate BETWEEN t2.datefrom AND t2.dateto
        WHERE t2.code = c.code AND thedate = d1.thedate
    )
)
OPTION (maxrecursion 365); --Default is 100, not enough to get all days between your dates
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be the below.

```
 WITH T1( Code, Date, Flag) AS
 (
 SELECT Code, DateFrom, 1 AS Flag
 FROM dbo.Test
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Code, dateTo, -1 AS Flag
 FROM dbo.Test
 ), T2 AS
 (
 SELECT *, SUM(Flag) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS ActiveMembershipCount
 FROM T1
 ), T3 AS
 (
 SELECT *, LAG(ActiveMembershipCount,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Date) AS PrevActiveMembershipCount
 FROM T2
 ), T4 AS
 (
 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Date)-1 AS RN
 FROM T3
 WHERE 0 IN (ActiveMembershipCount, PrevActiveMembershipCount)
 )
 SELECT Code, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)
 FROM T4
 GROUP BY Code, RN/2
 HAVING MIN(Date) <= '2018-07-01' AND MAX(Date) >= '2018-12-31'
```

NB: I haven't rigorously tested this for the scenario that a membership finishes and restarts on the same day so it may need some tweaks but the basic approach will work.